# No arbitrage for one period Binomial model option pricing - understanding the return function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

I am looking at lecture notes in mathematical finance. The prince $C$ of a European call option with strike $K$ and expiry time $T$ in a one period binomial model is derived via no arbitrage principle. The underlying asset price is $S$ at time $0$ and either $Su$ or $Sd$ at time $1$ and interest rate is $r$. Lecture notes says that the return function $r_{i}(j)$ at present time (time $0$ I assume) is the following:

$$r(1) = \left( \frac{Su - K}{1+r} - C\right)$$

(if asset price moves up), or

$$r(2) = \left( \frac{Sd - K}{1+r} - C\right)$$

if the asset moved down. Then the no arbitrage principle gives equation $p_{1}r(1) + p_{2}r(2) = 0$ from which $C$ is found, where $p_{1,2}$ are risk neutral probabilities.

I don't get how the return function is derived. My understanding would be that, one gets a loan of $(C+K)$ money to purchase the option with price $C$ and also have the ability to pay strike price $K$. But then the accrued interest at time $1$ on the loan is $(1+r)(C+K)$ which we need to pay back; so this equivalently should give the present value return as

$$\tilde{r}(1) =  \left( \frac{Su - K}{1+r} - C - K\right),  \qquad \tilde{r}(2) = \left( \frac{Sd - K}{1+r} - C - K\right) $$

So what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You only need a loan of $C$. The $K$ part you obtain by exercising the option. Hence why the value of the option at time $t=1$ is either $Su-K$ or $Sd-K$. Actually, it should be $(Su-K)_{+}$ or $(Sd-K)_{+}$, because in case the underlying is worth less than the strike, you simply will not exercise the option.

Even if you take into account you want to make a loan beforehand to buy the underlying later, you make a loan of $K/(1+r)$ for that and hence that is precisely what is accounted for in the formula already. Which makes your reasoning double count the loan.

At time $t=0$, you make a loan to buy the option, your account looks like this:

$$\begin{array} {r|r} \text{Active} & \text{Passive} \\ \hline \text{Option } & \text{Loan } C + K/(1+r)\\  
\text{Current account } K/(1+r) &    \end{array}$$

At time $t=1-\epsilon$, just before exercising your option:

$$\begin{array} {r|r} \text{Active} & \text{Passive} \\ \hline \text{Option} & \text{Loan } C(1+r) + K\\  
\text{Current account } K &    \end{array}$$

At time $t=1$ you exercise the option, i.e. buy the underlying for K and sell it for $X$:

$$\begin{array} {r|r} \text{Active} & \text{Passive} \\ \hline  & \text{Loan } C(1+r) + K\\  
\text{Current account } X &    \end{array}$$

At time $t=1+\epsilon$ you settle the loan, i.e. using $X$ to pay for it:

$$\begin{array} {r|r} \text{Active} & \text{Passive} \\ \hline  & \text{Loan } C(1+r) + K - X = 0\\  
\text{Current account } 0 &    \end{array}$$

So, if you want to settle everything $X-C(1+r)-K=0$.